# Finding the distances from each point to the rest, looping

Tags: pandas, loops, datatables

I am new to python.
I have a csv file containing 400 pairs of x and y in two columns. 
I want to loop over the data such that it starts from a pair (x_i,y_i) and finds the distance between that pair and the rest of the 399 points. I want the process to be repeated for all pairs of (x_i,y_i)  and the result is appended to to a list `Dist_i`

```
import pandas as pd
x_y_data = pd.read_csv("x_y_points400_labeled_csv.csv")

x = x_y_data.loc[:,'x']
y = x_y_data.loc[:,'y']


i=0
j=0
while (i<len(x)):
    Dist=np.sqrt((x[i]-x)**2 + (y[j]-y)**2)
    i = 1 + i 
    j = 1 + j
print(Dist)
```

output:

```
0      676.144955
1      675.503342
2      674.642602
..
396      9.897127
397     21.659654
398     15.508062
399      0.000000
Length: 400, dtype: float64
```

This is how far I went, but it is not what I intend to obtain. My goal is to get something like in the picture attached.
Thanks for your help in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nufwE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `broadcasting` (`arr[:, None]`) to do this calculation all at once. This will give you the repetitive calculations you want. Otherwise `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` gives you the upper triangle of the calculations.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
N = 6
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (N, 2)), 
                  columns=['X', 'Y'],
                  index=[f'point{i}' for i in range(N)])
```

---

```
x = df['X'].to_numpy()
y = df['Y'].to_numpy()

result = pd.DataFrame(np.sqrt((x[:, None] - x)**2 + (y[:, None] - y)**2),
                      index=df.index,
                      columns=df.index)
```

---

```
          point0    point1    point2    point3    point4    point5
point0  0.000000  2.853297  0.827596  1.957709  3.000780  1.165343
point1  2.853297  0.000000  3.273161  2.915990  1.172704  1.708145
point2  0.827596  3.273161  0.000000  2.782669  3.121463  1.749023
point3  1.957709  2.915990  2.782669  0.000000  3.718481  1.779459
point4  3.000780  1.172704  3.121463  3.718481  0.000000  2.092455
point5  1.165343  1.708145  1.749023  1.779459  2.092455  0.000000
```

---

With scipy.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

pdist(df[['X', 'Y']])
array([2.8532972 , 0.82759587, 1.95770875, 3.00078036, 1.16534282,
       3.27316125, 2.91598992, 1.17270443, 1.70814458, 2.78266933,
       3.1214628 , 1.74902298, 3.7184812 , 1.77945856, 2.09245472])
```

To turn this into the above DataFrame.

```
L = len(df)

arr = np.zeros((L, L))     
arr[np.triu_indices(L, 1)] = pdist(df[['X', 'Y']])
arr = arr + arr.T # Lower triangle b/c symmetric

pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns=df.index)

          point0    point1    point2    point3    point4    point5
point0  0.000000  2.853297  0.827596  1.957709  3.000780  1.165343
point1  2.853297  0.000000  3.273161  2.915990  1.172704  1.708145
point2  0.827596  3.273161  0.000000  2.782669  3.121463  1.749023
point3  1.957709  2.915990  2.782669  0.000000  3.718481  1.779459
point4  3.000780  1.172704  3.121463  3.718481  0.000000  2.092455
point5  1.165343  1.708145  1.749023  1.779459  2.092455  0.000000
```

Comment: thanks a lot for a good answer. so i next tried to get the values that are lets say less than 2, i tried to just add `result1=result<12` the output is correct , but it doesn't print the values, only True and False, can you show me how to get only values that are less? in the same or new dataframe